# Checking if okhttp response is fresh

Tags: java, okhttp

What is the best way to check whether the response is new, e.g. not coming from the cache? The rationale for this is that we want to do some expensive processing only in case the asset was modified.

Currently we have the following:

```
if ((response.networkResponse() != null &&
                response.networkResponse().code() == HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) ||
                response.cacheResponse() != null)
```

I wonder if this is the correct / best / succinct way of achieving this.

Comment: Can't you add a timestamp in the response header to have an idea of the age of this response ? Not a fan of cache so I might miss something ;)

Comment: This is served through CDN, so we prefer not to interfere with the standard HTTP practices. The code above works (I believe), I'm just not sure if this is the best way to do this with okhttp.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a cache response at all, the response was served from the cache. No need to check the network response.

Comment: Would it be null for the first request? I don't know the internals of okhttp, but since we enabled the cache, perhaps its behavior is "write-through", and cachedResponse is always != null.

Comment: The `cacheResponse()` will only be non-null if the cache was used.

Comment: @Roman I had the same issue, i.e. that `cacheResponse() != null` for all responses. I found [this issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3248) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727750/detect-if-okhttp-response-comes-from-cache-with-retrofit/41729479#41729479) explaining the reason behind this. If you want to check whether a response comes fully from the cache, I'd be checking `cacheResponse() != null && networkResponse() == null`.